# How to properly find supremum of a function $f(x,y,z)$ on a cube $[0,1]^3$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, inequality, supremum-and-infimum

Solving an applied problem I was faced with the need to find supremum of the following function 
$$f(x,y,z)=\frac{(x-xyz)(y-xyz)(z-xyz)}{(1-xyz)^3}$$
where $f\colon\ [0,1]^3\backslash\{(1,1,1)\} \to\mathbb{R}$.

I used Wolfram Mathematica and it resulted with *"there is no maximum in the region in which the objective function is defined"* and that the supremum is $\frac{8}{27}$ when $x,y,z\to 1$. I was able to verify some of it:
$$\lim\limits_{x,y,z\to 1}f(x,y,z) 
= 
\lim\limits_{x\to 1}f(x,x,x)
=
\lim\limits_{x\to 1}\frac{(x-x^3)^3}{(1-x^3)^3}
=
\lim\limits_{x\to 1}\frac{x^3(x+1)^3}{(x^2+x+1)^3}
=
\frac{8}{27}
$$ 
though I'm not sure how to justify the first equality. **Can I neglect direction of derivative in this case?**

And secondly, I don't know **how to show that $f(x,y,z)< \frac{8}{27}$ for all $x,y,z\in[0,1]^3\backslash\{(1,1,1)\}$.** When I tried to do that straightforwardly I drowned in computations.

Comment: Note that the function is symmetric with respect to each of its variables.

Comment: Your first equality is false (albeit not in a way that conflicts with the stated conclusion), since (say) $f(1, 1, z) = 0$ for $0 \leq z < 1$.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales, that's for sure. What does it give us?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang, oh, right, thanks. So that's all about inequality now

Comment: I thought I saw a way to use symmetry but I was wrong. Sorry for shooting from the hip.

Comment: Letting $x=t,\,y=\sqrt{t},\,z=\sqrt{t}$ I get $\lim_{t\to0}f(t)=\frac{9}{32}$ but since $\frac{9}{32}<\frac{8}{27}$ this does not resolve the question whether some other path would give a limit larger than $\frac{8}{27}$.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales, thanks. You meant $t\to 1$. The function seems to be increasing to (1,1,1) from any direction which would eliminate existence of maximum, but I can't prove that either.

Comment: Yes, thanks for catching that $t\to0$ error. Since you have access to Wolfram CAS you might try LaGrange multipliers on $L(x,y,z,\lambda)=f(x,y,z)-\lambda(x^2+y^2+z^2-1)$. If it happens that the maximum is $\frac{8}{27}$ on the unit ball, and since we already know that it approaches $\frac{8}{27}$ along one path, then you would have it. But perhaps those were the calculations that you "drowned" in?

Comment: I notice that the limit is also $\frac{8}{27}$ if $x=y=z=t\to-2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to find the maximum inside the unit cube of
$$f(x, y, z) = \frac{xyz(1-xy)(1-yz)(1-zx)}{(1-xyz)^3}$$

Now, suppose this maximum is when WLOG $y > z$.  Then we have
$$f(x, y, z) =  \frac{xyz(1-yz)(1-x(y+z)+x^2yz)}{(1-xyz)^3} < f(x, \sqrt{yz}, \sqrt{yz} )$$
as $y+z > 2\sqrt{yz}$.  Thus we must have $x=y=z$ for the maximum.  However,
$$f(t, t, t) =  \frac{t^3(1-t^2)^3}{(1-t^3)^3}=\frac{t^3(1+t)^3}{(1+t+t^2)^3}< \frac8{27}$$
as $27t^3(1+t)^3 < 8(1+t+t^2)^3 \iff 3t(1+t)< 2(1+t+t^2) \iff (1-t)(t+2) > 0$.

Finally we note that as $t \to 1$, $f(t, t, t)$ gets arbitrarily close to $ \frac8{27}$ so this is the supremum.

Answer (score 1):

tl; dr: The supremum of $f$ can be found by restricting to the diagonal of the cube and approaching $(1, 1, 1)$.

---

Partition the cube $C$ into level sets of $xyz$. If $0 < c < 1$, the level set
$$
L_{c} = \{(x, y, z) \in C : f(x, y, z) = c\}
$$
is compact, so $f$ achieves absolute extrema in $L_{c}$. (In fact, $L_{c}$ is homeomorphic to a closed disk, with three hyperbola arcs as boundary.)

To establish the bound
$$
f(x, y, z) \leq f(\sqrt[3]{xyz}, \sqrt[3]{xyz}, \sqrt[3]{xyz})
  = f(\sqrt[3]{c}, \sqrt[3]{c}, \sqrt[3]{c})\quad\text{on $L_{c}$,}
\tag{1}
$$
it suffices to show that the maximum of $f$ subject to $xyz = c$ occurs where $x = y = z$.

Assume from now on that $0 < c < 1$. Introduce the function $g(u) = u - \frac{1}{u}$ with domain $0 < u < 1$, and note that $ug'(u) = u + \frac{1}{u}$ is monotone for $0 < u < 1$.

On the surface $xyz = c$, we have $xy = \frac{c}{z}$, $xz = \frac{c}{y}$, and $yz = \frac{c}{x}$, so
\begin{align*}
f(x, y, z)
  &= \frac{(x - c)(y - c)(z - c)}{(1- c)^{3}} \\
  &= \frac{c - c(yz + xz + xy) + c^{2}(x + y + z) - c^{3}}{(1- c)^{3}} \\
  &= \frac{c - c^{2}(\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} + \frac{1}{z}) + c^{2}(x + y + z) - c^{3}}{(1- c)^{3}} \\
  &= \frac{c + c^{2}\bigl(g(x) + g(y) + g(z)\bigr) - c^{3}}{(1- c)^{3}}. \\
\end{align*}
Since the denominator is positive, this is maximized when $g(x) + g(y) + g(z)$ is maximized subject to $xyz = c$.

Lagrange multiplers gives $g'(x) = \lambda yz$, or $xg'(x) = c\lambda$, and similarly for $y$ and $z$. That is, the only critical points of $f(x, y, z)$ on the surface $xyz = c$ occur where
$$
xg'(x) = yg'(y) = zg'(z).
$$
Since $0 < x, y, z < 1$ on the cube and $u \mapsto ug'(u)$ is monotone (hence injective) in $(0, 1)$, the preceding implies $x = y = z$. That is, the only critical point of $f$ in the interior of $L_{c}$ (and hence the only possible interior extremum) is $(\sqrt[3]{xyz}, \sqrt[3]{xyz}, \sqrt[3]{xyz}) = (\sqrt[3]{c}, \sqrt[3]{c}, \sqrt[3]{c})$.

To conclude (1) holds, it remains to show that the boundary values of $f$ do not exceed the right-hand side. Because $f$ is symmetric, we may as well assume $x = 1$ and $yz = c$, so that
$$
f(x, y, z)
  = \frac{(y - c)(z - c)}{(1- c)^{2}}
  = \frac{c - c(y + z) + c^{2}}{(1 - c)^{2}}.
$$
This is maximized when $y + z$ is minimized, which is easily seen to occur where $y = z = \sqrt{c}$. Since
$$
f(1, \sqrt{c}, \sqrt{c}) < f(\sqrt[3]{c}, \sqrt[3]{c}, \sqrt[3]{c}),
$$
(a straightforward, if slightly tedious, one-variable calculation), (1) holds.